# 2005 Kia Amanti will turn over perfectly but wont start every time!

Tags: fuel-system, kia, cranks-wont-run, amanti

When i got the car I knew that it had issues with starting. I cleaned everything around the battery. It has a brand new air filter. Oil just got changed. New(ish) battery which is showing a full charge. I know that it may be fuel related but I am trying to narrow it down to what it might be specifically.

The first thing I am going to try is to look at the spark plugs and wires. I believe the O2 censor is fine. If the plugs are fine then I am going to check fuel pump and injectors. I am not sure if I even need to do all of this though.

My question is whether or not there is a good way to find out where to start?

Comment: Believe it or not I figured the issue out. Kinda funny story really.

Comment: I bought the car at an auction and in the glove box there was a receipt from when the previous owner had purchased a new set of keys. As it turns out because i had both keys on the same ring, whenever I was working on the car and I would get in the car to see if what I had done had fixed the issue I would just grab the keys and try and start it. As luck would have it sometimes I would start it with a key that was not working anymore. I could not figure out why the car would start sometimes and sometimes it wouldnt. Then today I had a buddy bring me to my house to work on the car and

Comment: I tried to start it and it would not start. I told him to hang on while I went inside and grabbed the other key and what do ya know it started right up. It has done so every time I have used that key sense and doesnt start when I use the other one......lesson is.....the simplest thing is usually the fix to the biggest issues.